# Use returned Array for Property

Tags: arrays, vb.net, properties

I want to set the values of an array, i return from a function, to a property.

**Property:**

```
Public Property Labels()() As String()
```

**Function:** (Return last 3 days)

```
Public Function LabelDays(count As Integer)
  Dim days(count)

  days(0) = Date.Now.ToString("ddd")
  count -= 1

  If count > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To count
      days(i) = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, i * -1, Date.Now).ToString("ddd")
    Next
  End If

  Return days
End Function
```

**Use:**

```
Labels = LabelDays(3)
```

I get the error like "Object cannot be converted to String".
If i set the values directly, it works.

```
'Labels = New String() {"We", "Tu", "Mo"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `As String` in your days array definition, so the array you are returning in your function is an array of objects. Just change this line:

```
Dim days(count)
```

Into this:

```
Dim days(count) As String
```

It's also worth noticing that you are creating one more item array that needed, so the line in fact should be:

```
Dim days(count-1) As String
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing code sets the `0` index twice, and for a `count` value of 3 would try to set *four* indexes (0, 1, 2, and 3). But the specific error is because *you didn't set a data type for the `days` array*. Without an explicit type, the compiler will choose `Object`. When you then try to assign it to a string, you get the `Object cannot be converted to String` error from the question. The function definition is missing a type as well.

**Always** set data types for your variables, even if it's just using type inference. You should enforce this by **turning on Option Strict**!

You can also get the whole function down to a one-liner:

```
Function LabelDays(ByVal Count As Integer) As String()
    Return Enumerable.Range(0, Count).Select(Function(d) Today.AddDays(d * -1).ToString("ddd")).ToArray()
End Function
```

Though to make it easier to read and maintain, I'd break it up a bit:

```
Function LabelDays(ByVal Count As Integer) As String()
    Dim range = Enumerable.Range(0, Count)
    Dim result = range.Select(Function(d) Today.AddDays(d * -1).ToString("ddd"))
    Return result.ToArray()
End Function
```

Note that those `range` and `result` variables still have explicit types, because of type inference and `Option Infer`, and because I assigned them at the same time that I declared them.

You can also have fun with an iterator:

```
Iterator Function LabelDays(ByVal Count As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim current = Today
    While Count > 0
        Yield current.ToString("ddd")
        current = current.AddDays(-1)
        Count -= 1
    End While
End Function
```

And then call it like this:

```
Labels = LabelDays(3).ToArray()
```

Comment: thanks for the tips! but i marked pikoh's answer because he was a bit faster and it also helped :)